# shell_exec() not running program & giving incomplete output

Tags: php, c, shell, ubuntu, php-5.5

I am **running a shell script(which runs a C program) using shell_exec() in php but program is not running and the output generated is incomplete.**

php file:

```
<?php
$output =passthru('./heatmap -vid cctv5.mp4 2>&1');
echo $output;
var_dump($output);
echo "Done with Heatmap";
?>
```

Output of shell_exec()

```
This program shows how to use background subtraction OpenCV videos (-vid) and images (-img). Usage: ./bs {-vid
```

Output in terminal:

```
This program shows how to use background subtraction
OpenCV  videos (-vid) and images (-img).
Usage:
./bs {-vid <video filename>|-img <image filename>}
for example: ./bs -vid video.avi
or: ./bs -img /data/images/1.png
-----------------------------------------------------

Number of Frames: 6866; FPS: 29.97
MIN: 0; MAX: 15.6861
MIN: 0; MAX: 255
Channels:firstframe: 3; Channels:display: 3
Time taken: 1.23121
Time taken per frame: 0.00432003
```

I tried **exec() , passthru() but none was able to run the program and all produced same incomplete output.**

Comment: Look at the *real output* ("view source"). It's HTML, so will be cut off at `<`. Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) for HTML context escaping.

Comment: may be the output is not showing bcz of that but y not the program running?

Comment: Any number of reasons. Why not look at the complete output to find out?

Comment: where to look for complete output? echo htmlspecialchars("$output"); is producing same result. :(